# What is safest way to install 20.04 with Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I've done this before on my machines, but this one belongs to my wife! I usually have success, but sometimes it turns in to a time consuming nightmare.

EDIT
How about this for safety?

- Buy new small drive
- Install Linux OS with only new drive connected
- Run this way to get accustomed
- Connect both drives and modify Windows boot manager to point to new drive as a secondary choice.
  /EDIT

Computer is ACER desktop ATC-605-UB11
HD has only one partition large enough for an OS.

I tried running MINT from the USB stick and it worked great.
Also would like GRUB to default to Windows at least in the beginning.
Should I use windows partition tool or Ubuntu.
Thanks!
Stan

Comment: This seems to deal mostly with Win 8 and older Ubuntu. I am hoping things have improved.

Comment: "Improved" must come from the Windows side. Linux developers have taken ease-of-install as far as they can on their side.

Comment: Maybe I'll just run from the USB stick, since it seems to work fine. I'll research a way to save my settings etc.

Comment: Acer has unique requirement of setting "trust". Other systems do not have that. Older example, but should be similar: Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot